# MS Azure - Can a single organization have multiple organizations under it?

Tags: azure, database-migration

I'm looking into transitioning all our company systems to MS Azure from our current on-premises setup. We have multiple affiliates operating using their versions of the same system (i.e. a custom built application that is fundamentally the same but is tailor fit to specific business cases/industries.

Is it possible for our mother company to register for MS Azure, and the affiliates exist as separate organizations on that plan? or is each organization required to have its own Azure subscription?

Many Thanks,
Jevb

Answer (score 0):

I saw many different implementations of Azure for companies. Mostly based on per-separate-subscription model, sometimes I saw working with 1 subscription and then splitting teams to Resource Groups, I think it is all up to the company, budgets and goals.

I would recommend to read first these, maybe this will give you some hints how to start and migrate :)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/reference/azure-scaffold
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/decision-guides/subscriptions/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/management-groups/overview

Answer (score 0):

You can have one tenant for your whole company, and individual subscriptions for each business case. The way that Azure does billing it is nice to split your industries into separate subscriptions until you have a solid tagging strategy in place.

I would highly suggest looking into management groups within Azure as you start to implement policy and RBAC for your individual subscriptions so that you can adhere to security best practices and avoid repeating yourself.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/subscriptions-licenses-accounts-and-tenants-for-microsoft-cloud-offerings?view=o365-worldwide
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/management-groups/overview